# adjusting table to page, hbox too big to fit

Tags: tables, margins, width

I've seen various examples but I am unable to adjust the table to the page accordingly as I continue to get errors when trying the adjust width or textwidth methods:

```
\begin{table}[hb!]
\centering
\captiontargets for protein assay measurements}
\begin{tabular}{clcl}
Protein Feature & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Input Features}       & Target             &   \\ 
\cline{1-3}
Activity        & Sequence, Substrate, Enzyme Activity    &   \\
Expression      & Sequence, New Host                       & Protein Expression &   \\
Stability       & Sequence, Detergent     & Thermal Stability  &   \\
\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: welcome -- have a look at the answer below

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should provide complete small document, which we can compile as it is, not just code fragment. What is in the fourth column? You also should consider to use rules defined in `booktabs7 package instead of `hline`s.

Answer (score 1):

Two versions uing `booktabs` for the horizontal lines and `tabularx`  or `tabular*` to make sure the table fits into the available textwidth.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hb!]
\centering
\caption{targets for protein assay measurements}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xl}
\toprule
Protein Feature & Input Features                        & Target            \\ 
\midrule
Activity        & Sequence, Substrate, Enzyme Activity                       \\ \addlinespace
Expression      & Sequence, New Host                    & Protein Expression \\ \addlinespace
Stability       & Sequence, Detergent                   & Thermal Stability  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[hb!]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{targets for protein assay measurements}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
\toprule
Protein Feature & Input Features                        & Target            \\ 
\midrule
Activity        & Sequence, Substrate, Enzyme Activity                       \\ 
Expression      & Sequence, New Host                    & Protein Expression \\ 
Stability       & Sequence, Detergent                   & Thermal Stability  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hb!]
        \centering
%       \captiontargets for protein assay measurements}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Protein Feature} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Input Features}       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Target}   \\ 
        \cline{1-3}
        Activity        & Sequence, Substrate, Enzyme Activity    &   \\
        Expression      & Sequence, New Host                       & Protein Expression   \\
        Stability       & Sequence, Detergent     & Thermal Stability   \\
        \cline{1-3}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for following up but I still get a margin problem.. :/

Answer (score 0):

With `booktabs` table defined in the `tabularray` package (version 2021P):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hb!]
\caption{Targets for protein assay measurements}
\label{tab:tblr}
\begin{booktabs}{
    colspec = @{} l X[l] l @{},
    rowsep=3pt
                }
    \toprule
Protein Feature & Input Features                        
                    & Target        \\
    \midrule
Activity        & Sequence, Substrate, Enzyme Activity
                    &               \\ 
Expression      & Sequence, New Host                    
                    & Protein Expression \\
Stability       & Sequence, Detergent                   
                    & Thermal Stability  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]